# Why do we use a non-primitive unit cell for the brillouin zone of these metals?

Tags: crystals, fermi-energy

I'm reading through a textbook and they defined a primitive unit cell as a unit cell with only one lattice point in it.
The Brillouin zone is defined as a primitive unit cell of the reciprocal lattice (or equivalently the reciprocal unit cell to the real space primitive unit cell).

Then later on there are diagrams and discussions about the fermi surfaces of some metals such as Potassium and Calcium. Potassium is said to be in a BCC structure, and Calcium in an FCC structure. However, neither of these are their primitive unit cells (Potassium's BCC unit cells has 2 lattice points per unit cell).

I can't spot what I've misunderstood and can't find much online as it's not a very specific question.

Here's an example of the diagram. The wire framing is the Brillouin zone boundary.
[image]

Comment: The nice square _conventional_ unit cell is not a primitive unit cell.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by square, since I'm talking about 3D cells. If you mean simple cubic, or any type of cubic, then I know it's not a primitive unit cell. This is exactly my issue